# UTF8 real decode

Tags: php, html-entities, utf8-decode

Possibly a very simple question , but I was wondering how I can decode utf8 characters into readable characters.

For example :

```
L&#x27;heure supr&#xEA;me
```

Into

**L'heure suprême**

I tried the following :

```
utf8_encode , utf8_decode And `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");`
```

The output never gave me the correct characters , for example

```
 html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); returned L'heure suprÃªme
```

EDIT :
It was a stupid question ,  `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, "ISO-8859-15");` did the trick

Comment: Those are **HTML entities**, not UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your results to be properly displayed, you'll need to tell the receiving end, which encoding is used:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

$string = 'L&#x27;heure supr&#xEA;me';
print html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

The output without explicitly naming a charset encoding provokes undefined behavior. Earlier today, someone suggested [a great article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on Unicode and Character sets. It makes for a good read and I'll suggest you "skim over" it.

Comment: It is not for displaying , but matching on different sources.

Comment: @Paolo You're still better off, using `UTF-8`, though. Your `ISO-8859-1` encoded string might end up with lots of question marks (`L'heure supr?me`) in it.

Comment: My table is unicode , but my source (different iso websites ), I need sometimes to compare names and it won't work if the charachters are different.

Comment: My problem was fairly unrelated, but thanks for the line of html_entity_decode. That, coupled with mb_detect_encoding is great.